# Не работают две функции одновременно

Tags: php, mysql

В общем, делаю функции для вывода из баз двух значений. Код вот такой вот

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("123", "123", "123", "123");
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE `unique_id` = $playerCookieId");

function printAvatar($result_set){
    while(($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc())!=false){
        echo $row["avatar_medium"];
    }
}
function printName($result_set){
    while(($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc())!=false){
        echo $row["name"];
    }
}
printAvatar($result_set);
printName($result_set);


$mysqli->close();
```

Так вот, проблема в том, что выводится только что–то одно: либо ссылку на аву, либо имя.

Comment: Логично, один и тот же набор данных два раза читать нельзя. Вопрос в том, зачем нужны отдельные функции, почему бы все данные не получать в одной

Answer (score 2):

`$mysqli->query` возвращает датасет. `fetch_assoc` проходит датасет построчно. После вызова первой функции по окончании цикла указатель датасета сдвинется на последний элемент, по этому цикл второй функции не отработает. `fetch_assoc` будет возвращать `false`.

Вам необходимо обрабатывать датасет в одном цикле, либо сбрасывать указатель в начало датасета перед каждым [циклом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439230/how-to-go-through-mysql-result-twice)

И, раз уж на то пошло, `$result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM`users`WHERE`unique_id`= $playerCookieId");` - тут у Вас потенциальная sql инъекция.